# How to share iPhone location with iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, geolocation, gps, ibeacon

Now what I don't mean is sending a location manually to the iPad. Consider this scenario: I'm on the road and want to use my iPad for navigation. I prefer it to the iPhone due to the larger display. Unfortunately, the iPad doesn't have GPS. But my iPhone does!

Is it possible to continuesly share the current location from my iPhone to my iPad? So that apps on my iPad can access my location via location services?

I've looked into *iBeacons*. At first that sounded promising. Although there are apps that promise to turn my iPhone into an iBeacon, none of those advertised to continuesly update the location. I'm beginning to have doubts, that an iBeacon is even supposed to update its location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

While you can share your iPhones location with your iPad via various Apps or the native Find My feature, Navigation Apps will rely on the location of the iPad - the iPad cannot use the iPhone location as if it were the iPad's own location.